# According to the theory of structural functionalism, what causes social disequilibrium?

Tags: political-philosophy, society, sociology, structuralism, functionalism

I understand that the basic premise of [structural functionalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_functionalism) is that social institutions serve the function of maintaining social stability and promoting social solidarity, but I don't understand what causes social institutions, according to functionalism, to become dysfunctional and reach a state of social disequilibrium.

What causes social institutions to fail according to structural functionalism?

Why would the crime rate rise to socially unacceptable levels, for example, according to structural functionalism?

Why would a civil war break out in a country according to structural functionalism?

Comment: It is a good question, but apparently Structural Functionalism was falling out of favor 60 years ago (from the page you linked). What prompts your question?

Comment: I was looking for alternative theories for social conflict to Marxism such as offensive realism in international relations. I'm trying to compile a list of distinct and non-overlapping social conflict theories.